# Calling PHP function doesn't work in index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a function I wrote in my functions.php page for a gallery to display on certain pages. It displays on custom templates, but now I need it to display on index.php Here is the code from my functions.php file:

```
function min_get_page_gallery( $echo = true) {
global $post;



$show_gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_gallery-show', true);

if ( empty($show_gallery) ) {
    return;
}

$gallery      = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_image_advanced', false);

ob_start();
?>
<div class="gallery" id="gallery-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
    <button class="gallery-move-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"     aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <div class="image_container clearfix">

        <?php
            $count = count($gallery);
            $num = ceil($count / 3);
            //$width_container = $num  * 100;
            //$width_row = 100 / $num;
            //echo '<div class="gallery_inner" style="width:' . $width_container . '%;">';
            echo '<div class="gallery_inner">';
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) {
                    //echo '<div class="row" style="width: ' . $width_row . '%;">';
                    echo '<div class="row'. (0 == $i ? ' active': ' inactive') .'">';
                }
                echo '<div class="col-sm-4 img_container' . (0 == $i ? ' active': ' inactive') . '">';
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($gallery[$i], 'thumb-gallery');
                echo '</div>';
                if ( $i % 3 == 2  || ($i+1) == $count) {
                    echo '</div>';
                }

            }
            echo '</div>';
        ?>
    </div>
    <button class="gallery-move-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
<?php
$return = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if ( $echo ) {
    echo $return;
    } else {
      return $return;
  }

 }
```

That code works like a charm. Here is where I call it as min_get_page_gallery(); in awards.php where it works flawlessly:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Awards Page Template */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="container" id="block-no-sidebar">
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div id="award-list">
    <?php echo min_get_awards(); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php min_get_page_gallery(); ?>
</div>
   <?php min_get_page_tabs(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now finally, I try to add the same function call of min_get_page_gallery(); in my index.php file like this:

```
    <?php
    // Silence is golden.
       if ( ! defined ( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
       exit;
       }
    ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

        <style class="take-to-head">
            #block-main-content-with-sidebar { background: #ffffff; }
        </style>

        <div class="container" id="block-main-content-with-sidebar">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                l('block-' . get_post_type());
            endwhile; else:
                l('block-none' );
            endif;

           ?>

       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
          <?php l('block-sidebar'); ?>
       </div>   
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <?php min_get_page_gallery(); ?>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Is there something I'm missing??

Comment: I don't see this in your code but how do you include functions.php in index.php?  Do you use 'require' or 'require_once'?  functions.php must be included in index.php before you can call any functions from functions.php

Comment: @CharlesEF ahhh I see let me check

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem?

Comment: No unfortunately....

Comment: I know nothing about Wordpress so I can't point you in any direction.  As a test have you tried to use the 'require' command in index.php to include the functions.php file?

Comment: I actually figured it out about an hour ago, but thanks so much

Comment: Can you post the answer?  Posting your solutions might help others who read this thread.

Comment: I just did. It's up now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had to do some tweaking to get the meta to show in functions.php I added these lines: 
    `$pagemain = is_page();`

and then:

```
 if ( $pagemain == is_page( 35393 )  ) {
    $meta[] = array(
        'id'         => 'imageupload',
        'post_types' => array( 'page'),
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',
        'title'  => __( 'Image Gallery', 'min' ),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name'  => __( 'Show', 'min' ),
                'id'    => "{$prefix}_gallery-show",
                'desc'  => __( '', 'meta-box' ),
                'type'  => 'checkbox',
                'clone' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'id'               => "{$prefix}_image_advanced",
                'name'             => __( 'Image Advanced', 'min' ),
                'type'             => 'image_advanced',
                // Delete image from Media Library when remove it from post meta?
                // Note: it might affect other posts if you use same image for multiple posts
                'force_delete'     => false,
                // Maximum image uploads
                //'max_file_uploads' => 2,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to describe in more detail, what is wrong with your `index.php`? Is some output when load `input.php`, or blank page?

Is correctly defined `ABSPATH`? If not, your script exit on the beginning.

For more specific awareness of flow through the script, try to write there some `echo`

E.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo "Before calling min_get_page_gallery()" ?>
    <?php min_get_page_gallery(); ?>
    <?php echo "After calling min_get_page_gallery()" ?>
</div>
```

Then look, if you can see the messages from echo before and after calling the desired function.

Comment: Thanks von Oak. It prints those 2 messages fine, but no gallery.

Comment: The index.php actually works great, it's just that call for the gallery function isn't working.

Comment: Do you have enabled error reporting?   `error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);` For testing purposes add these lines to the beginning of your script.

Comment: Yes, add it to the beginning of index.php.

Comment: Thanks let me do that now

Comment: I did that no specific error pertaining to that page

Comment: Try to refine the message reporting for function `min_get_page_gallery()` in `functions.php` via `echo "$name_of _the_variable_you_are_interested"`. E.g. in your case after assigning value to `$show_gallery` look at this variable via `echo "$show_gallery"` or `var_dump($show_gallery)`. And so on for other variables you are interested, if they have appropriate values. The more advanced is debugging via [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) (look at it), but it's long story...